# Layout for both orientations in dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

i'm able to create custom dialog but not able to achieve this kind of layout can anyone please help me. Is it possible to achieve this kind of layout in dialog??should i use tablayout or linear layout for both orientation ???

Thanks in advance

Comment: android supplies an AlertBuilder/DialogBuilder with lots of options. have you tried it for your purpose?

Comment: ya but i need the kind of layout for both orientations

Comment: do you have 2 separate xml files for the 2 orientations?

Comment: no i'm trying with single layout :( is it possible to load different layouts for a dialog ???

Comment: you should start marking the answers for your questions if they solved the problem for you. (of your 7 questions, only one has an accepted answer, and it was one you answered yourself). otherwise people will be less inclined to write up answers for you. thanks.

Comment: @invertigo the solution which u gave did'nt solve my problem but still i gave upvote for ur answer b'coz of ur response  :) and most of my question are not answered to be accepted :)

Comment: @Downvoter can u please leave a comment so that i can improve my question or search for better result...

Answer (score 0):

yes, its possible to load different layouts. just drop the 2 layouts in the appropriate folders (layout-land, layout-port) and you should be good.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: will try and let u know :)